# Limit with Next and Previous buttons using PHP & Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to have encountered a problem implementing this code into my page.
Basically I'm trying to put a limit of 5 on the display from the database which can be changed using next and previous buttons.
I got it to work separately but I think the problem is the fact that I have my pages displayed as variables in an array and when either button is clicked it tries to send 2 variables to the link which doesn't work.
Can anyone tell me any solution ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please include your code! Have a read of [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using the get variable in the URL to determine which page of the site you're on and that's interfering with the get variable being used to change the items being displayed from the database? If Yes Then 
You can use more than one variable in the URL so you just have to change the url to something like this :

```
<?php
   $dbPage = (isset($_GET['dbpage']) ? $_GET['dbpage'] : 1);
   $nextPage = $dbPage + 1;
   $prevPage = ($dbPage == 1 ? 1 : $dbPage - 1);
?>
<a href="mysite.com?page=<?=$_GET['dbpage']?>&dbpage=<?=$prevPage?>">Previous</a>
<a href="mysite.com?page=<?=$_GET['dbpage']?>&dbpage=<?=$nextPage?>">Next</a>

$page_number = (isset($_GET['dbpage'])) ? $_GET['dbpage'] : 1;
$news_per_page = 10;

$limit = ($page_number - 1) * $news_per_page;
$q = "SELECT * FROM your table LIMIT $limit, $news_per_page" ...
```

Comment: This is very helpful & what I'm looking for , thank you Mouad

Comment: You Welcome, and don't forget to mark this answer as correct :)